# Linked List only displaying the first node

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }

}

class practice {
    public static Node insert(Node head, int d) {
        if (head == null)
            head = new Node(d);
        else {
            Node cn = head;
            while (cn != null) {
                cn = cn.next;
                cn = new Node(d);
                cn = cn.next;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }

    public static void display(Node head) {
        Node start = head;
        while (start != null) {
            System.out.print(start.data + " ");
            start = start.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node head = null;
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        while (N-- > 0) {
            int ele = sc.nextInt();
            head = insert(head, ele);
        }
        display(head);
    }
}
```

I was trying to create a linked list with head as the node pointing the starting node of the list. And adding `n` elements to the tail of the list. But when trying to display the list, I am getting only the first element as the output.

For example,
for the input

```
3
4
5
6
```

The output is `4` when it should be `4 5 6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `insert` method fails to insert any node in the case that the `head` already exists.  It creates a new `Node`, but then ignores it.

Instead, search for the end of the list, looking for a `null` `next` reference.  Then, set the `next` reference to a new `Node`.

```
else
{
    Node cn = head;
    while (cn.next != null)
    {
        cn = cn.next;
    }
    cn.next = new Node(d);
}
```

Comment: Tried it!
Still getting the first element as the output!

Comment: After submitting the input `3 4 5 6` (meaning 3 items -- 4, 5, 6), I get the expected output with my changes - `4 5 6`.

Comment: Yeah!
Got it!
Made a mistake!